# How to understand non LR(0) reduce state in A pratical method for constructing efficient LALR(k) Parsers with Automatic Error Recovery

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar, eclipse-jdt, lr-grammar, lalr

[image: This is where the term "non-LR(0) reduce state]

I don't get where the non-LR(0) reduce state comes from.
Does it means that :

1. Remove the LR(0) reduce state  And the get  LR'(0) states
2. The use LR'(0) states to generate a LR(K)  states . and the non LR(0) reduce state come from the LR(K) states.

This is a copy of [A  patyical method for cnstructing efficient LALR(K) Parders with Authomatic Error Recovery](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxcTRY0Zp6wndnNhMkYwcENVSUE/view?usp=sharing)

Please read chapter 4.2

Answer (score 1):

A reduce state is a state in which a reduction is possible. That is, if the state's itemset contains a final item, the state is a reduce state.

If a reduce state is LR(0) -- which means that the state's action can be identified without any lookahead -- then the state's itemset must be only a single item, which must be final. (If that were not the case, the state could not be LR(0), because there would be more than one possible action available, only distinguishable by the lookahead.)

As he points out, the LR(0) reduce action must be correct, because no other action was possible in that state. So even if the lookahead token will generate an error requiring error recovery, the reduction will not need to be undone. So the author proposes removing LR(0) reduce states.

Of course, not all states are LR(0). In most states, the action taken will depend on the lookahead. In particular, in a non-LR(0) reduce state, the reduction will be contingent on the lookahead token. And, after LR(0) reduce states are removed, *all* remaining reduce states are non-LR(0).

But because table compression may replace an error action with a default reduction (and, I think, because of LALR state merging, although it's possible that this chapter isn't about LALR), it is quite possible that the reduction indicated for the lookahead token will actually turn out to be incorrect. In that case, the reduction may need to be undone in order to recover from the error.

The author's assumption seems to be that undoing reductions is not, in general, possible, and therefore the parser needs to defer the reduction actions (including the stack modification) until the reductions are known to be definitely valid, which will be when the parser eventually performs a shift. The rest of the chapter concerns accomplishing this goal.